# i am tried this console problem. TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, error-handling, axios

> i dont understand where i miss-tack when i run this code show the error in console ( TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>   ) can you tell me how can i solve this problem ?

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_url = "  http://localhost:3000/contacts";

window.onload = () => {
  const mytbody = document.querySelector("#mytbody");
  axios
    .get(BASE_url)
    .then(res => {
      res.data.forEach(function(contact) {
        createTDelement(contact, mytbody);
      });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

function createTDelement(contact, perentElement) {
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");

  const tdId = document.createElement("td");
  tdId.innerHTML = contact.tdId;
  tr.appendChild(tdId);

  var tdName = document.createElement("td");
  tdName.innerHTML = contact.name;
  tr.appendChild(tdName);

  const tdEmail = document.createElement("td");
  tdEmail.innerHTML = contact.email;
  tr.appendChild(tdEmail);

  const tdPhone = document.createElement("td");
  tdPhone.innerHTML = contact.phone ? contact.phone : "N/A";
  tr.appendChild(tdPhone);

  const tdAction = document.createElement("td");

  const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
  editBtn.className = "btn btn-warning";
  editBtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
  editBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("i am editable");
  });
  tdAction.appendChild(editBtn);

  const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.className = "btn btn-danger";
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete";
  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("i am editable");
  });
  tdAction.appendChild("deleteBtn");

  perentElement.appendChild("tr");
}
```

Comment: You quoted `deleteBtn` and `tr` by mistake when you called `appendChild`

Answer (score 0):

`perentElement.appendChild("tr");` and `tdAction.appendChild("deleteBtn")` will try to add the **strings** "tr" and "deleteButton" as child to `perentElement` / `tdAction`. Because strings are no `NodeElement`s, you receive this error. You cannot append strings as children to DOM Elements using `appendChild()` method.

Further reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns